# Unable to use a self-signed certif. on localhost

Tags: ubuntu, arch-linux, ssl, certificates, https

I created a self-signed certificate for localhost for testing as follows:

```
openssl genrsa -out key.pem 2048
openssl req -new -key key.pem -out certificate.csr
openssl x509 -req -in certificate.csr -signkey key.pem -out certificate.pem
```

I specified "localhost" at FQDN. That's it, I haven't done anything else and haven't copied them anywhere and all 3 files are in the directory of my app.

When I'm running a web server  which is not apache or nginx on localhost, I get the following error:

```
$ curl -v https://localhost:3345
* Rebuilt URL to: https://localhost:3345/
*   Trying ::1...
* connect to ::1 port 3345 failed: Connection refused
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 3345 (#0)
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS alert, Server hello (2):
* SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate
* Closing connection 0
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS alert, Client hello (1):
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate
More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl performs SSL certificate verification by default, using a "bundle"
 of Certificate Authority (CA) public keys (CA certs). If the default
 bundle file isn't adequate, you can specify an alternate file
 using the --cacert option.
If this HTTPS server uses a certificate signed by a CA represented in
 the bundle, the certificate verification probably failed due to a
 problem with the certificate (it might be expired, or the name might
 not match the domain name in the URL).
If you'd like to turn off curl's verification of the certificate, use
 the -k (or --insecure) option.
```

If that matters, here's my code:

```
startApp = do
  let port = 3345
  print $ "Listening the port " ++ (show port) ++ " ..."
  let tls = tlsSettings "certificate.pem" "key.pem"
  runTLS tls (setPort port defaultSettings) app
```

So you see I'm using "pem" and "pem", not "csr" and the port 3345.

I'm on Arch, but I'll need a solution for Ubuntu as well.

How can I fix the error?

Note that in a browser I also have an error . In particular in FF:

`The owner of localhost has configured their website improperly. To protect your information from being stolen, Firefox has not connected to this website.`

Answer (score 2):

Curl uses your system's trust store to ascertain trust of certificate chains by default. This trust store contains a list of trusted CA certificates. Since you've self signed and are not using a chain that leads to a CA certificate in the trust store, curl fails your request because it doesn't trust your chain.

Either:

1. Get your CSR signed by a trusted certificate authority instead of self-signing ([Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) is free and trusted by almost every trust store due to the root cert it chains to), or
2. Add your certificate to your system trust store, or
3. Use `--cacert <your cert>` to trust only this cert, or
4. Use `curl -k` (Not recommended since no verification is done)

Comment: which of the files should I use in "--cacert <your cert>"?

Comment: wait, it's not only curl, it's a browser also.

Comment: For browsers, you either have to add the certificate to their trust stores as well, or bypass their warnings (also not recommended for the same reasons). You might just consider using something like [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) instead.

Comment: I have an error when trying to import my certificate to a browser "This personal certificate can't be installed because you do not own the corresponding private key which was created when the certificate was requested." I'm the one who generated it. Any ideas?

Comment: It sounds like you're importing it as a client certificate, but that's not what you want. You need to add it to the trust store, instead.

Comment: how can I do that?

Comment: how can I do that?

Comment: how can I do that?